# How do I display both Gregorian and Persian dates in the Calendar app?

Tags: macos, calendar, internationalization, language

How do I display both Gregorian and Persian dates in the Calendar app?

It only allows "lunar" alt calendars, not Jalali/Persian calendars.

[image]